# MQTT ACL file usage

Tags: c++, mqtt, acl, mosquitto

I am new to MQTT and I would like to test the access control list function.
I am testing with mosquitto, MQTT v3.1 broker.
I have the following for my ACL file:

```
topic read $SYS/#
topic readwrite #         <---- anyone without a username can publish to any topic

user test                 <---- only a client with username test can subscribe to the topic test
topic readwrite testTopic/#
```

Here is what I got when I run the broker:

```
sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf -v
1541640112: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Wed, 05 Sep 2018 15:51:27 -0300) starting
1541640112: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1541640112: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1884.
1541640112: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1884.
1541640113: New connection from ::1 on port 1884.
1541640113: New client connected from ::1 as 3 (c1, k60).
1541640113: Sending CONNACK to 3 (0, 0)
1541640113: Received SUBSCRIBE from 3
1541640113:     testTopic (QoS 1)
1541640113: 3 1 testTopic
1541640113: Sending SUBACK to 3
1541640114: New connection from ::1 on port 1884.
1541640114: New client connected from ::1 as 1 (c1, k60, u'test').
1541640114: Sending CONNACK to 1 (0, 0)
1541640114: Received SUBSCRIBE from 1
1541640114:     testTopic (QoS 1)
1541640114: 1 1 testTopic
1541640114: Sending SUBACK to 1
1541640115: New connection from ::1 on port 1884.
1541640115: New client connected from ::1 as 2 (c1, k60).
1541640115: Sending CONNACK to 2 (0, 0)
1541640115: Received PUBLISH from 2 (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'testTopic', ... (4 bytes))
1541640115: Sending PUBACK to 2 (Mid: 1)
1541640115: Sending PUBLISH to 3 (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'testTopic', ... (4 bytes))
1541640115: Received DISCONNECT from 2
1541640115: Client 2 disconnected.
1541640115: Received PUBACK from 3 (Mid: 1)
1541640118: Socket error on client 1, disconnecting.
1541640118: Socket error on client 3, disconnecting.
```

with a client with user name 'test' subscribe to the topic testTopic:

```
mosquitto_sub -t 'testTopic' -p 1884 -d -q 1 -u test -i 1
Client 1 sending CONNECT
Client 1 received CONNACK
Client 1 sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: testTopic, QoS: 1)
Client 1 received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 1
```

with a client without user name subscribe to the topic testTopic:

```
mosquitto_sub -t 'testTopic' -p 1884 -d -q 1 -i 3
Client 3 sending CONNECT
Client 3 received CONNACK
Client 3 sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: testTopic, QoS: 1)
Client 3 received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 1
Client 3 received PUBLISH (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'testTopic', ... (4 bytes))
Client 3 sending PUBACK (Mid: 1)
1724
```

and a client publishing to the topic testTopic:

```
mosquitto_pub -t 'testTopic' -m '1724' -p 1884 -d -q 1 -i 2 
Client 2 sending CONNECT
Client 2 received CONNACK
Client 2 sending PUBLISH (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'testTopic', ... (4 bytes))
Client 2 received PUBACK (Mid: 1)
Client 2 sending DISCONNECT
```

The question is, why client with username test does not receive the message 1724?

EDIT:
I have also tried to change the publish topic and subscribe topic to testTopic/foo without changing the ACL file, and the result is the same:

Broker:

```
sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf -v
1541967842: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Wed, 05 Sep 2018 15:51:27 -0300) starting
1541967842: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1541967842: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1884.
1541967842: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1884.
1541967844: New connection from ::1 on port 1884.
1541967844: New client connected from ::1 as 1 (c1, k60, u'test').
1541967844: Sending CONNACK to 1 (0, 0)
1541967844: Received SUBSCRIBE from 1
1541967844:     testTopic/foo (QoS 1)
1541967844: 1 1 testTopic/foo
1541967844: Sending SUBACK to 1
1541967861: New connection from ::1 on port 1884.
1541967861: New client connected from ::1 as 3 (c1, k60).
1541967861: Sending CONNACK to 3 (0, 0)
1541967861: Received SUBSCRIBE from 3
1541967861:     testTopic/foo (QoS 1)
1541967861: 3 1 testTopic/foo
1541967861: Sending SUBACK to 3
1541967875: New connection from ::1 on port 1884.
1541967875: New client connected from ::1 as 2 (c1, k60).
1541967875: Sending CONNACK to 2 (0, 0)
1541967875: Received PUBLISH from 2 (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'testTopic/foo', ... (4 bytes))
1541967875: Sending PUBACK to 2 (Mid: 1)
1541967875: Sending PUBLISH to 3 (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'testTopic/foo', ... (4 bytes))
1541967875: Received PUBACK from 3 (Mid: 1)
1541967875: Received DISCONNECT from 2
1541967875: Client 2 disconnected.
```

with a client with username 'test' subscribe to the topic testTopic/foo:

```
mosquitto_sub -t 'testTopic/foo' -p 1884 -d -q 1 -u test -i 1
Client 1 sending CONNECT
Client 1 received CONNACK
Client 1 sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: testTopic/foo, QoS: 1)
Client 1 received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 1
```

with a client without username subscribes to the topic testTopic/foo:

```
mosquitto_sub -t 'testTopic/foo' -p 1884 -d -q 1 -i 3
Client 3 sending CONNECT
Client 3 received CONNACK
Client 3 sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: testTopic/foo, QoS: 1)
Client 3 received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 1
Client 3 received PUBLISH (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'testTopic/foo', ... (4 bytes))
Client 3 sending PUBACK (Mid: 1)
1724
```

and a client publishing to the topic testTopic:

```
mosquitto_pub -t 'testTopic/foo' -m '1724' -p 1884 -d -q 1 -i 2 
Client 2 sending CONNECT
Client 2 received CONNACK
Client 2 sending PUBLISH (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'testTopic/foo', ... (4 bytes))
Client 2 received PUBACK (Mid: 1)
Client 2 sending DISCONNECT
```

The question remains, why client with username test does not receive the message 1724?

Comment: What happens if you publish & subscribe to `testTopic/foo` rather than `testTopic`

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for your suggestion, and I have edited the post with the topic change. And the question remains the same.